# Spark 1.5.1, Scala 2.10.5: how to expand an RDD[Array[String], Vector]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am using Spark 1.5.1 with Scala 2.10.5

I have an **`RDD[Array[String], Vector]`** for each element of the RDD:

- I want to take each `String` in the `Array[String]` and combine it
  with the `Vector` to create a **tuple `(String, Vector)`**, this step will lead to the creation of several tuples from each element of the initial RDD

The goal is to end by building an RDD of tuples: **`RDD[(String,
   Vector)]`**, this RDD contains all the tuples created in the previous step.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this :

```
rdd.flatMap { case (arr, vec) => arr.map( (s) => (s, vec) ) }
```

(The first `flatMap` lets you get a `RDD[(String, Vector)]` as an output as opposed to a `map` which would get you a `RDD[Array[(String, Vector)]]`)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
// rdd: RDD[Array[String], Vector] - initial RDD
val new_rdd = rdd
  .flatMap {
    case (array: Array[String], vec: Vector) => array.map(str => (str, vec))
  }
```

Toy example (I'm running it in spark-shell):

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array((Array("foo", "bar"), 100), (Array("one", "two"), 200)))
val new_rdd = rdd
  .map {
    case (array: Array[String], vec: Int) => array.map(str => (str, vec))
  }
  .flatMap(arr => arr)
new_rdd.collect
res14: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((foo,100), (bar,100), (one,200), (two,200))
```